# BitExchange Error (crypto currency exchange script)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cryptography, bitcoin

I've installed on my VPS the script BitExchange (an crypto exchange script)
But I have the follow errors:

1. The homepage and the login page don't show. (only I can see the admin page)
2. The "site settings" on Admin page don't save. (click Save buton, page reloads but don't save)

Somebody can help me?

This is the "apache error log":

> [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.625140 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$shared_dir in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/autoload.php on line 14
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.629349 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$shared_dir in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/autoload.php on line 14
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630113 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: loginform in /var/www/html/admin/lib/common.php on line 44
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630130 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: loginform in /var/www/html/admin/lib/common.php on line 44
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630145 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: user_info in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/User.php on line 18
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630163 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: logout in /var/www/html/admin/lib/common.php on line 45
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630176 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: print in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 10
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630184 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: current_url in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 11
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630191 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: current_url in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 11
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630498 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: action in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 12
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630525 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bypass in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 13
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630535 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 15
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630563 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: target_elem in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 16
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.630599 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: this_query in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 20
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.635962 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$shared_dir in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/autoload.php on line 14
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.636642 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$language in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Header.php on line 114
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.636660 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: language in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Header.php on line 131
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.636680 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: authy_form in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 64
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.636685 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: loginform in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 370
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.636709 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$shared_dir in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/autoload.php on line 14
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.657804 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$shared_dir in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/autoload.php on line 14
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668697 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: form_table in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 20
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668718 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: enctype in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 23
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668722 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: loginform in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 24
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668725 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: verify_fields in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 25
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668730 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: temp_files in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 26
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668733 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: urls in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 27
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668737 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: attached_file_fields in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 28
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668740 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: record_id in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 29
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668743 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: unique_fields in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 32
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668746 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: compare_fields in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 33
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668749 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: delete_whitespace in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 34
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668752 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: includes in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 39
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668756 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$form_output_started in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 47
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668759 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$in_include in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 47
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668764 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: loginform_info in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 128
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668847 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pass in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 385
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668873 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 3705
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668891 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 3710
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668981 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 176
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.668994 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: method_name in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 182
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669001 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: req_img in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 182
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669012 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: j in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 200
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669017 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: grid_input in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 200
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669023 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 3705
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669029 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 3710
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669041 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 213
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669046 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: method_name in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 219
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669052 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: req_img in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 219
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669059 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 1779
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669065 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: method_name in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 1791
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669084 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bs_db_name in /var/www/html/admin/index.php on line 389
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669089 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$o_method_suppress in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 228
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669093 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bs_db_name in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 232
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669097 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 3705
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669101 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 3710
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669109 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 247
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669112 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 253
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669118 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Form::$create_record in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 2728
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669135 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$form_legend in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 2748
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.669431 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/lib/Ops.php on line 19
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.670123 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 2761
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.670140 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$in_include in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 2769
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.670149 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: in_group in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 2804
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.670170 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: in_group in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 2804
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.670182 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: in_group in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 2804
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.670191 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: in_group in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 2804
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.670207 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$in_include in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 2906
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:44:52.670268 2018] [:error] [pid 3806] [client 5.224.137.225:50005] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$pm_editor in /var/www/html/admin/shared2/Form.php on line 2959
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.251163 2018] [:error] [pid 3804] [client 5.224.137.225:50012] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$default_timezone in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 92
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.251230 2018] [:error] [pid 3804] [client 5.224.137.225:50012] PHP Notice:  date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '' is invalid in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 92
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.251261 2018] [:error] [pid 3804] [client 5.224.137.225:50012] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$default_timezone in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.251416 2018] [:error] [pid 3804] [client 5.224.137.225:50012] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone () in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php:93\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php(93): DateTimeZone->__construct('')\n#1 /var/www/html/frontend/htdocs/login.php(41): include('/var/www/html/f...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.545886 2018] [:error] [pid 3807] [client 5.224.137.225:50014] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$default_timezone in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 92
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.547972 2018] [:error] [pid 3807] [client 5.224.137.225:50014] PHP Notice:  date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '' is invalid in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 92
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.547988 2018] [:error] [pid 3807] [client 5.224.137.225:50014] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$default_timezone in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93
>   [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.548051 2018] [:error] [pid 3807] [client 5.224.137.225:50014] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone () in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php:93\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php(93): DateTimeZone->__construct('')\n#1 /var/www/html/frontend/htdocs/login.php(41): include('/var/www/html/f...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93

---

frontend/lib/common.php (line 93)

> $dtz = new DateTimeZone($CFG->default_timezone);

Comment: This is why: `[Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.251416 2018] [:error] [pid 3804] [client 5.224.137.225:50012] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone () in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php:93\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php(93): DateTimeZone->__construct('')\n#1 /var/www/html/frontend/htdocs/login.php(41): include('/var/www/html/f...')\n#2 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93`

Comment: You have a fatal PHP error. A fatal error causes the entire script to kill itself. Here your fatal error looks like you are using a "bad timezone" in your common.php (in your `frontend/lib/` directory) file on line 93. How are you writing that line? Share the code...

Comment: $dtz = new DateTimeZone($CFG->default_timezone);

Comment: common.php (line 93): $dtz = new DateTimeZone($CFG->default_timezone);

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think I get what's wrong with your script:

Let's step backwards for a minute:

Your script dies here:

> [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.251416 2018] [:error] [pid 3804] [client 5.224.137.225:50012] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone () in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php:93\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php(93): DateTimeZone->__construct('')\n#1 /var/www/html/frontend/htdocs/login.php(41): include('/var/www/html/f...')\n#2 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93

This is telling you that your `common.php` file has, in line 93, a call to PHP `DateTimeZone` class which passes an invalid parameter. In this case it is just an empty string: `''`.

Next let's look at the previous error entry:

> [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.251261 2018] [:error] [pid 3804] [client 5.224.137.225:50012] PHP Notice: Undefined property: object::$default_timezone in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93

Notice here you have the Undefined property `object::$default_timezone`. This simply means that `$default_timezone` has not been set. Which explains the simple `''` parameter you are passing to the `__construct()` of PHP's `DateTimeZone`

Next, this simply confirms what we have been looking at:

> [Fri Sep 28 00:45:05.251230 2018] [:error] [pid 3804] [client 5.224.137.225:50012] PHP Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '' is invalid in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 92

Your `Timezone ID === ''`. This value is Invalid. It will always break your script.

For proper timezones look at [PHP's doc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

An example:

```
$CFG->default_timezone = 'America/New_York';
$time = $dtz = new DateTimeZone($CFG->default_timezone);
```

This should - from your errors - provide a solution.